# Sort an array containing similar objects keeping maximum distance

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, distance

I have to find out an algorithm which allows to sort an array containing strings. Strings in this array can be the same.

E.q. ['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'pineapple', 'pineapple', 'strawberry']

My point is I need to sort this array in order to keep the similar strings with the maximum distance between themselves. For example, one sorted, my array needs to be like that :

E.q. ['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'pineapple', 'strawberry', 'pineapple']

This algorithm needs to run one on the array to initialize this sort and needs to handle insertions and deletions.

May this kind of algorithm already exists but I cannot find it out.

Thanks you !

[Update]

Sometimes the array cannot be sorted in this way, for example if there is a lot a "pineapple" regarding other elements. But when it possible, two similar elements needs to be as far as possible in the array.

Comment: Why not ['pineapple','apple', 'orange',  'strawberry', 'pineapple', 'apple',]

Comment: Clarify the question, it's grossly underspecified as is.

Comment: Yes you right, the only thing is that one element cannot be next to his similar. Of course some times it's impossible (if there is a lot of the same element) but just try to keep the maximum distance.